# Functioning the searchview in actionbarsherlock

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock, searchview

I have a `sherlockactivity` that `implements` an `onItemClickListener`. Then I create a new `ListView` and put data in it, I want to create a *search* at the top in the `actionbarsherlock` like a lot of famous apps.

This is my code:

```
 @Override
 public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
     SearchView searchView = new
             SearchView(getSupportActionBar().getThemedContext());
     menu.add("Search")
             .setActionView(searchView)
             .setShowAsAction(
                     MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_IF_ROOM
                             | MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_COLLAPSE_ACTION_VIEW);

     return true;
 }
```

**currently**, the word "search" appears at the top of my `actionbarsherlock`. If I click on it, a `textfield` will appear in the `actionbarsherlock`. **But** when I type anything or click `search` (In the keyboard) nothing happens. What am I missing?

Comment: and what do you want to happen?

Comment: the listview updates with my characters, like lots of apps that have searching functionality.

Comment: did you read this: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/search/search-dialog.html#UsingSearchWidget ?

Comment: Yup, still it is no answering my qes.

Comment: did you implement any SearchView's callback?

Comment: Nope, the only code I've used is in the question

Comment: so add OnQueryTextListener and implement your search

Comment: can you show me how ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These two are the methods you need to override to control when the user types on the SearchView and when the user clicks on the search button:

```
public class MyClass extends SherlockActivity implements SearchView.OnQueryTextListener{
...

    @Override
    public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Then you need

```
searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(this);
```